# Wrong kernel version with driver, how do I adapt it?

Tags: drivers, kernel, kubuntu, versions

that's my third question about a driver installation... So, I've bought a wi-fi key, and I'm trying to install the driver with a simple make. But it looks like the kernel version is the wrong, because the supporting kernels are 2.4 and 2.6, but mine is 5.something.
How I am supposed to install my driver, in that case ?
When I do a make, the konsole tells me this .

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~/Desktop/DPO$ sudo make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools'
/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7662u
chipset = mt7632u
chipset = mt7612u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/symbol.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:391: LINUX] Error 2
```

Here's the driver : https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/mt7612u

I'm a new Kubuntu user so I would be greatful if you explaining everything.

EDIT :
Here are some important informations :

```
ubuntu@kubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13fe:4200 Kingston Technology Company Inc. USB DISK 2.0
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-26-generic
```

When I do lsusb with my Wi-fi key, the konsole doesn't write anything and crashes.

Here is the product : https://www.amazon.fr/PiAEK-1200Mbps-Adaptateur-Antenne-Windows/dp/B082KPTBQH/ref=sr_1_36?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=clef%2Bwifi&qid=1588667364&sr=8-36&th=1
(That's in french, I'm sorry about that)

System's informations :
KDE Plasma Version : 5.18.4
KDE Frameworks Version : 5.68.0
Qt Version : 5.12.8
Kernel version is written above
OS-Type : 64-bit

I'm running Kubuntu with Oracle VM VirtualBox, but it should'nt change anything.

Comment: What is "7.idk" kernel version?  What is your wireless device? Is it a USB device? Then please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: To start with, which  release number of  Kubuntu is installed?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Done ! So what can we do ?